# 7.8 LAB: Word frequencies (lists and CSV) - How can I read a csv and eliminate duplicates?

Tags: python, csv

Here is the code I have but I cannot figure out how to remove the duplicates. I've tried making new lists, dict, tuples, etc.

---

Write a program that first reads in the name of an input file and then reads the file using the csv.reader() method. The file contains a list of words separated by commas. Your program should output the words and their frequencies (the number of times each word appears in the file) without any duplicates.

Ex: If the input is:

`input1.csv`

and the contents of input1.csv are:

`hello,cat,man,hey,dog,boy,Hello,man,cat,woman,dog,Cat,hey,boy`

the output is:

```
hello 1
cat 2
man 2
hey 2
dog 2
boy 2
Hello 1
woman 1
Cat 1
```

Note: There is a newline at the end of the output, and input1.csv is available to download.

```
import csv
user_input = input() 
with open(user_input, 'r') as name_CSV: 
    paper_copy = csv.reader(name_CSV)
    for lines in paper_copy:
        for w in lines: 
            words_cnt = lines.count(w)
            print(w, words_cnt)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a few things to unique a `list` but the best thing is to just convert it to a `set` ([what is a set in python?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)).

So first load in your words with `csv.reader` as you are told:

```
import csv

word_list = []
with open('input1.csv') as name_CSV:
    paper_copy = csv.reader(name_CSV)
    for line in paper_copy:
        for word in line:
            word_list.append(word)
```

Then convert it to a `set`. I sorted the `set` to preserve the order that the words show up in from `word_list` because `set`'s don't innately keep any order (they are, by definition, unordered).

```
unique_words = sorted(set(word_list), key=word_list.index)
```

And then to get your output, `for loop` through all of your unique words in your `set` and compare them to your words in your `list` while also incrementing the count of those words each time you hit them in the `for loop`:

```
for x in unique_words:
    count = 0
    for y in word_list:
        if x == y:
            count += 1
    print(x, count)
```

Output:

```
hello 1
cat 2
man 2
hey 2
dog 2
boy 2
Hello 1
woman 1
Cat 1
```

Or, you could do it with less lines with `count()`. I still think it is a good idea to at least look at the above method and try to understand how that works.

```py
for x in unique_words:
    print(x, word_list.count(x))
```

Output:

```
hello 1
cat 2
man 2
hey 2
dog 2
boy 2
Hello 1
woman 1
Cat 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

word_list=[]
user_input = input() 
with open(user_input, 'r') as name_CSV: 
    paper_copy = csv.reader(name_CSV)
    for lines in paper_copy:
        for w in lines: 
            word_list.append(w)
word_set = set(word_list)
unique_words = sorted(set(word_list), key=word_list.index)
for x in unique_words:
    count = 0
    for y in word_list:
        if x == y:
            count += 1
    print(x, count)
```

Answer (score 0):

a very pythonic way could be to add all the words to a list and convert the list to a set, then your done

sets only allow 1 instance of a literal, so converting a list of strings to a set {set are in curly braces like dictionaries} removes all duplicates immediately

```
import csv

word_list=[]
user_input = input() 
with open(user_input, 'r') as name_CSV: 
    paper_copy = csv.reader(name_CSV)
    for lines in paper_copy:
        for w in lines: 
            word_list.append(w)
word_set = set(word_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to this lab. You can use a set as someone else already mentioned as sets are unique in that they do not allow duplicate words. Another approach is to create a list and use the count() feature:

```
# Needed for using csv.reader()
import csv

# The list used to check for duplicates
my_list = []

# You are taking input for the name of the csv file and only reading it.
with open(input(), 'r') as csvfile:
    # Reads the file and makes a list with whatever elements are delimited.
    word_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    
    # Obtains the row of words from word_reader.
    for row in word_reader:
        # Iterates through each word in the row.
        for word in row:
            # Adds each word to my_list.
            my_list.append(word)      
            
            # If only one instance of word is present in my_list:
            """ Statement does not execute if a duplicate word is added to
            my_list because then my_list.count(word) != 1 """ 
            if my_list.count(word) == 1:
                # Print the word followed by how many times it occurred in row.
                print("{} {}".format(word, row.count(word)))
```